# Need to get output of command as value for variable in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm new to writing shell script. I need to get the output as a variable to following condition.

The output of below command is 0, but i could see 1 when i declare as a variable. Can someone please help where i made a mistake and how to get exact output as a variable..

```
$ db2 -x "select reorg_status from SYSIBMADM.SNAPTAB_REORG where REORG_STATUS <> 'COMPLETED'" | wc -l
0
```

But,

```
$ status=`db2 -x "select reorg_status from SYSIBMADM.SNAPTAB_REORG where REORG_STATUS <> 'COMPLETED'" | wc -l`
$ echo $status
1

status=$(db2 -x "select reorg_status from SYSIBMADM.SNAPTAB_REORG where REORG_STATUS <> 'COMPLETED'" | wc -l)
echo $status
1
```

Zero is outcomes,So, I need 0 should be the variable instead of 1..

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` after `"COMPLETED'"` - your command may be outputting on `stderr` rather than `stdout`

Comment: What does the output look like if you don't pipe it to `wc -l`?